# Python Tkinter: Accurately receive events whenever clock's milliseconds place is 0

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a digital clock in Tkinter, and I am looking for a more accurate way to update clocks.

## What I wish to achieve

I want to receive an event whenever the milliseconds place is 0. That is, a function will be called whenever it is 09:30:00:000, 09:30:01:000, 09:30:02:000, etc. This seems to be better in terms of reducing the error, but I cannot find such schedulers for tkinter.

Is such an event possible in tkinter?

## Simple but imperfect solution

A simple way to update the clock is to do so every 1000 milliseconds:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

class Clock:
    frame = ttk.Frame(root)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Initialize the label
        self.time_label = ttk.Label(self.frame)
        self.time_label.grid()

        # Update the time
        self.time_label.after(0, self.update_time)

    def update_time(self) -> None:
        # Call the function again after 1000 milliseconds.
        self.time_label.after(1000, self.update_time)

        # Update the display.
        self.time_label.configure(text=datetime.today().strftime(r"%H:%M:%S"))

Clock()
root.mainloop()
```

While this suffices for simple solutions, it can be inaccurate. For example, if `update_date_time` is called at, say, 09:30:00.900, the clock will be delayed by around 900 milliseconds. Besides, because the function might not be called on time, the delay would fluctuate over time.

Of course, I can make it update every 100ms (or even smaller interval) instead of 1000ms, but that seems to be wasteful on resources. Besides, the error is still there. That's why I want to receive timed events.

Comment: "I want to receive an event whenever the milliseconds place is 0... For example, if update_date_time is called at, say, 09:30:00.900, the clock will be delayed by around 900 milliseconds.." Did you try **checking what time it is** when handling the event the current time, and then using that information to figure out how long it should be until the next call? Other than that, no, there isn't a meaningful question that can be solved here; `.after` and related tools are really all you get to work with, and anything else is just a wrapper.

Comment: To get **guaranteed precise** timing requires a real-time systems language (Python isn't one, and neither is anything else that offers garbage collection, realistically) **and** a real-time operating system (your home computer almost certainly does not use one).

Comment: Thanks, I made it check the time and wait until the milliseconds place reaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice I could check the time and subtract. I fixed it by replacing the line with:

```py
self.time_label.after(
    ((datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=1)).replace(microsecond=0) - datetime.now()).microseconds // 1000,
    self.update_date_time
)
```

This computes the time until the microseconds reaches 0, then divide by 1000 and round to obtain the number of milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, but event timing in Windows and Linux is simply not that precise, because timers are only checked at scheduler intervals.  If you ask to sleep for 123 milliseconds,  the only guarantee is that you will awaken AT LEAST 123 milliseconds from now.  Typically, it will be within about 15ms of that point.  Fortunately your digital clock doesn't need to update on a millisecond-accurate basis.  After all, your screen only updates every 16ms.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to receive an event whenever the milliseconds place is 0 ...
> Is such an event possible in tkinter?

No, it’s not possible. The `after` method makes no guarantees about executing a function at a specific time. It only guarantees it won’t call a function early.